# iPad keyboard not showing up when on in-document linked websites in Google Docs and Google Slides apps

Tags: keyboard, ipad, links, google-docs

I have got an iPad 6th gen which is updated to iPadOS 16.2.

I sometimes use Google Docs to save some links (that open in Google Docs itself, I've set it to be like that). For example, I saved a link to [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/tv), which I tried to access (it worked as usual), but when I wanted to make a search, the keyboard wouldn't show up. The input field shows a blue line (see circled part on screenshot below) as usual to show where I'm at when typing but not the keyboard!

I need to copy text from Quick Notes (easiest way I found) and then paste it in the search bar.

Here is a picture of it happening: [image: screenshot of input field on archive.org showing the cursor but no keyboard showing]

I browsed answers on this website and on the internet for this kind of problem but I haven't found anything working for me.

It happened to me this morning (March 8th, 2023) for the first time.

How do you fix this problem?
Thanks to any help that could be provided.

Comment: Does this happen only in Google Docs, or elsewhere as well, eg. input fields in Safari? — Have you checked your iPad's keyboard settings? Settings > General > Keyboard, and make sure that the toggle next to "Enable Dictation" is turned on. You can also try toggling the "Auto-Capitalisation", "Auto-Correction" and "Check Spelling" settings on and off to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @AlexIxeras , this happens on Google Docs and on Google Slides apps. I just tried those but they do not change anything.

Comment: Other things that came to mind were: 1) Does this only happen in the Google apps, or other places as well? 2) Have you tried different browsers? 3) Have you tried clearing the cache and cookies? 4) Have you tried the Google Docs iPad app (https://apps.apple.com/au/app/google-docs-sync-edit-share/id842842640)? If so, try maybe reinstalling it.

Comment: @AlexIxeras This happen on google apps only, clearing cookies and cache does nothing. And I am already using the app.

Comment: Ok, and not that I'd have a solution at hand, but does the problem persist if you access Google Docs via Safari or Chrome or Firefox? I guess you have tried deleting and re-installing the Google Docs app?

Comment: It does not happen on Safari, only in Google Docs and Google Slides apps. My iPad is partially managed centrally and I cannot delete an app. But I have tried on my iPhone but it seems to work all the time. @AlexIxeras

Comment: Ok, so we have narrowed the culprit down, but not really why. Is there a version difference between the one on your iPad and the most recent version on your iPhone? Could you ask your IT support to updated these two apps?

Comment: @AlexIxeras My iPhone is running iOS 16.3.1 and my iPad iPadOS 16.2. But both apps seem to be at the same update since none of them show the little blue circle next to their name (on home screen). But this is maybe because the one on my iPad is running the latest Google Docs update that could be ran with iPadOS 16.2 but I think this is quite improbable. I normally can update apps, they allowed me this, but it does not show me the option when I long-press on the app (is there another way?).

Comment: Not sure if I'm thinking of the same blue circle as you. This blue circle (or blue dot) is an indicator if you have recently updated an app. I really don't know much about the differences between iOS and iPad OS, in the sense as to why the app would work on one device but not on another. If your iPad is managed, then you might not be able to update these apps. I was once working for a company who provided me with a managed iPhone and I could not update apps within the walled off ecosystem.

Comment: @AlexIxeras Yes, that's the blue dot I'm talking about. I didn't know it was for this. I'm gonna ask the IT department to re-install those apps.

Comment: @AlexIxeras Ok, it's re-installed. It seems to work but I'll tell you if it happens again :) Thanks!

Comment: No prob. Glad the reinstall appears to have worked.